# Deploying a maven site to Nexus-3 via https

Tags: maven-3, maven-site-plugin, nexus3

Ok, so here's the situation:

I have a multimodule Maven project (currently using `v3.5.2`) which has a large site deployment, some time back I deployed the Maven site (`mvn clean site site:deploy`) to a Nexus-2.x site repository using simple `http`.

After migrating to Nexus-3.8.0 I considered to put the whole server bedind a behind a reverse proxy allowing `https` only, which ran pretty fine so far. Unluckily I'm unable to deploy a site to the new raw repository, which is supposed to hold the sites from my maven project.

The configuration currently looks like this

```
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <locales>en_US</locales>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Running the command above gives me

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.7:deploy (default-cli) on project server-policies: Wagon protocol 'https' doesn't support directory copying -> [Help 1]
```

My site configuration looks like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <site>
        <id>sites-repository</id>
        <url>dav:https://nx3.mydomain/repository/prd-${project.artifactId}</url>
    </site>
    ...
</distributionManagement>
```

Is there any way to upload sites to a Nexus-3.x repository using https?

Comment: Can you show your `<site>` configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You have to use http for the site repositories.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're experiencing results from having a  `distributionManagement.site.url` ends with a `/`

Assuming you have a `<servers><server><id>sites-repository....` set properly in your settings file, this will work fine.

Execute `mvn help:effective-pom` and look at your `<distributionManagement>` section.

Comment: Note that `dav:https://nx3.mydomain/repository` must (somehow) point to a hosted raw repository.

Ours looks more like `dav:https://nx3.domain/repository/sites` where `sites` is a hosted repository of type `raw`.

Comment: Our repo is proxied behind a  LB on AWS, so YMMV with this.